# Time Complexity -- Recursion

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recursion

It's been a long time since I've studied time complexity in school, but I've been tasked with finding the time complexity of an algorithm.  Here is the algorithm in a pseudo-pseudocode (yes, two pseudos because I'm not good at creating pseudocode.  Haha!).

```
main()
{
  list = methodImportFromCSV(...)   // Don't care about this line's complexity

  tree = createRootNode()    // O(1)

  DO
    count = tree.createChildren(list)
  WHILE count > 0
}
```

---

```
createChildren(list) : returns integer
{
  nodesCreated = 0

  foreach (node in this.children)
  {
    nodesCreated += node.createChildren(list)
  }

  groups = separateIntoGroups(list) // O(n)

  foreach (group in groups)
  {
    if (someMethodThatReturnsTrueOrFalse(group) = true) // Some method is O(n) of the group
    {
      this.children.Add(new child())
      nodesCreated += 1
    }
  }

  return nodesCreated
}
```

---

You can see that the method is recursive and just creates a tree structure.  I remember a few things just as linear iteration is `[O(n)]`, but I've never had to deal with recursion before.  Is it permissible to state that the algorithm is running at `O(n * t)`?  Perhaps I am wrong?  I thank you, all, for your assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: [Our reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) may help.